# Regular expression for removing inner double quotes

Tags: java, regex, csv

I have a String with outer double quotes `""`. There are inner double quotes that I need to remove. What is a regular expression for this?

For example:

> input: "Hello there "I arrive" tonight" ---> output: "Hello there I
>   arrive tonight"
>   input: "Hello there "I arrive tonight"" ---> output:
>   "Hello there I arrive tonight"
>   input: ""Hello" there I arrive tonight"
>   ---> output: "Hello there I arrive tonight"

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work with my examples 2 and 3. It works for example 1.

```
data.replaceAll("\"(\\b[^\"]+)?\"\\b([^\"]+)\\b\"([^\"]+\\b)?\"","\"$1$2$3\"");
```

Background: I have a CSV file, which I need to parse. The data comes with inner quotes inside the outer quotes. For example:

```
"aa","bb","cc","dd "REMOVE QUOTES" "
"aaa","bbb","ccc",""REMOVE QUOTES" ddd "
```

I would like the Regexp to remove the inner quotes only and keep the outer ones. Output:

```
"aa","bb","cc","dd REMOVE QUOTES "
"aaa","bbb","ccc","REMOVE QUOTES ddd "
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of negative look-behind and look-ahead:

```
data = data.replaceAll("(?<!^)\"(?!$)", "")
```

- `(?<!^)` Negative look-behind for start of line
- `(?!$)` Negative look-ahead for `EOL`

Comment: No he tried a very involved regex. I was wondering why so complex :)

Comment: I suppose it pays to read the last paragraph. I stand corrected.

Comment: I have just tried it, the expression removes all double quotes "

Comment: This expression works on all the original quotes. A [CSV parser](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) is more appropriate for parsing CSVs.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot. I get the inside string (ignoring the outer quotes) then remove all quotes and add the outer ones back.

```
String input1 = "\"Hello there \"I arrive\" tonight\"";
String output1 = "\"" + input1.substring(1, input1.length() - 1).replaceAll("\"", "") + "\"";
System.out.println(output1);
```

Ouput

> "Hello there I arrive tonight"

Comment: Thanks guys, data string is CSV lines like the this: "aa","bb","cc","dd "REMOVE QUOTES" " <CRLF> "aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd "REMOVE QUOTES" " etc.. I want to remove the inner quotes and keep the outer ones

Answer (score 0):

If I suppose that your strings begin with the first " and finish with the last ", you can use this for a regex way:

```
data.replaceAll("(?<!^)\"(?!$)", "");
```